# parsing json string to angular object from http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to parsing this response from http get and display the value into a detail modal but I dont know how to parse it. I have using arc to show me the response of my http get,here is my image of my response using arc.

[image: This is my response]

here is my.js file

```
$http.get('.....a='+$scope.month).then(function(response){
        $scope.coba = response.data;
```

Comment: First, there is no "angular object", angular is a framework and uses javascript objects, in response.data you have a javascript object, you don't need to parse anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(response.data)` or `angular.toJson(response.data)`, it will parse the http response into JSON. 
If it is failing, means your response is not exact JSON